# Creating statically linked executable using GCC

Tags: gcc, mono, g++, opensuse

I am creating the Embedded Mono Archive for one of my application. As per [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/) link I need to create c/c++ executable which will instantiate appropriate framework and will load my managed assembly into it.

I tried creating the statically linked executable by specifying -static in g++ commandline but did not worked. below is verbose output from my g++ command -

```
$>g++  -Wall -o monolauncherstatic.out MonoLauncher.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` -v -static

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: i586-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --disable-libitm --disable-plugin --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-linker-build-id --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-linux-futex --without-system-libunwind --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --build=i586-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012] (SUSE Linux) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-o' 'monolauncherstatic.out' '-D' '_REENTRANT' '-I' '/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0' '-L/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib' '-v' '-static' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D _REENTRANT MonoLauncher.cpp -quiet -dumpbase MonoLauncher.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase MonoLauncher -Wall -version -o /tmp/cc9htj2d.s
GNU C++ (SUSE Linux) version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012] (i586-suse-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012], GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0
 /usr/include/c++/4.7
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/i586-suse-linux
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/include-fixed
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (SUSE Linux) version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012] (i586-suse-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012], GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 909fa5113dc6c530ae791996b13c020f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-o' 'monolauncherstatic.out' '-D' '_REENTRANT' '-I' '/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0' '-L/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib' '-v' '-static' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/as -v -I /usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0 --32 -o /tmp/ccwER6Jm.o /tmp/cc9htj2d.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.1 (i586-suse-linux) using BFD version (GNU Binutils; openSUSE 12.3) 2.23.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Wall' '-o' 'monolauncherstatic.out' '-D' '_REENTRANT' '-I' '/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0' '-L/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib' '-v' '-static' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/collect2 --build-id -m elf_i386 -static -o monolauncherstatic.out /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/crtbeginT.o -L/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../.. /tmp/ccwER6Jm.o -lmono-2.0 -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.7/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't have static libraries installed, e.g. `libc.a`, `libm.a`, `libpthread.a`, etc.

If you're using SuSE, perhaps `yum install glibc-devel-static` will work.  Maybe some of the other libraries will need other packages to be installed.